# Magento 1.9 Small Business in Germany / remove tax information‏ / inkl 0 % MWST

Tags: tax, magento-1.9

I search a solution to modify my new Shop Magento 1.9 for a Small Business in Germany.

The correct name in Germany is : Kleinunternehmer Regelung (Small Business Rule)

In this solution I must remove the tax and tax information and change this with a special sentence: "UST.- frei gem Kleinunternehmer Regelung §19 USTG".

Answer (score 1):

In the past we have used [MageSetup](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup) when setting up basic tax information for German specific shops. This will pre-configure your shop with some basic tax rules and settings.

It includes the tax rule for companies that do not need to pay tax:

```
<products_no_vat tax_rate="tax_calculation_rate_3"
                                     tax_customer_class="customers_companies_no_vat"
                                     tax_product_class="product_rate_1,products_rate_2,shipping_rate_1,shipping_rate_2">
    <execute>1</execute>
    <code>Ust.-befreite Unternehmen kaufen voll- und ermäßigtbesteuerte Artikel</code>
    <priority>2</priority>
    <position>0</position>
</products_no_vat>
```

Comment: I use MageSetup in the latest version with the following configuration:

Product tax class: no tax

Customer tax class: company's without UST tax

After this settings all article get the not correct note:
Inkl. 0% MwSt., zzgl. Versandkost

The Magesetup community writes it's a Magento problem not a magesetup problem:

https://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup/issues/31

I search a solution to solve this issue in a clean way

Other websites writes a solution but for older version and I need a solution with the newest version:
http://simon.zambrovski.org/2012/03/magento-kleinunternehmer/

Answer (score 0):

I use MageSetup in the latest version with the following configuration: 
Product tax class: no tax 
Customer tax class: company's without UST tax

After this settings all article get the not correct note: Inkl. 0% MwSt., zzgl. Versandkosten

The Magesetup community writes it's a Magento problem not a magesetup problem: http://github.com/firegento/firegento-magesetup/issues/31 
I search a solution to solve this issue in a clean way

Other websites writes a solution but for older version and I need a solution with the newest version: http://simon.zambrovski.org/2012/03/magento-kleinunternehmer

It would be great if you have any good ideas